# Should this be part of an oil heater?

Tags: heating, heater, radiator, epoxy, radiant-heating

I have an old oil heater that emits a faint odor once heated. Thinking it must be just dust burning off, I took it apart and wiped it completely clean of dust, but the odor persists. I've narrowed it down to one single part. The place where the heating element enters the heater enclosure seems to be covered in some glossy substance which, when emitted, produces odor (see picture).

My question: is this substance some sort of epoxy or sealant that's integral to the functioning/safety of the heater, or is it just residue from some plastic part that melted long ago, in which case it would be safe to scrape off?
[image]